# {Newbie Question} How to run latest Python version

Tags: raspbian, python

So I decided to buy myself a Raspberry Pi. (whohoo)

After installing the latest Raspbian I want to update Python
If I run `python -V` the terminal gives me :`Python 2.7.16`

If I do this:
`sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential libpq-dev libssl-dev openssl libffi-dev zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-pip python3.7-dev`

It tells me that I already have installed the latest version.

Now how can I get it to run the latest version.

The thing is I want to install `svgwrite`. This needs `Python 3.6` at least.

Comment: Use python3 to run python programs. The default python version is python2 in Buster.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version will run with the command `python3`, which is a symbolic link to the most recently installed version of CPython 3.  From the look of the installation commands you used it will be CPython 3.7.

Comment: okay. Thnx. Didn't know that.
I do this command `sudo pip install svgwrite` (from a tutorial) but I don't know how to run the command `python3` instead of `python`

Comment: The `pip` command is also usually a symlink or a copy of a versioned pip file (e.g. pip2.7, pip3.7, pip3.8, etc.). You should be able to use the explicitly numbered version directly. Alternatively you can invoke it with a specific CPython installation like this: `/usr/local/bin/python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade svgwrite`

Answer (score 1):

Use python3 as the command to start the Python 3 interpreter.  The command python runs the default Python version which is still Python 2.